# how to add and remove a user role in the selection menu discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

```
class PastelColor(discord.ui.Select):
def __init__(self):
    options = [
        discord.SelectOption(label="Lemon Chiffon", value="1129910267531231313"),
        discord.SelectOption(label="Bluish White", value="1129910494719922186"),
        discord.SelectOption(label="Tea Rose", value="1129910499627245688"),
        discord.SelectOption(label="Very Light Purple", value="1129910504089993377"),
        discord.SelectOption(label="Mauve", value="1130080414988501034"),
        discord.SelectOption(label="Wisteria Krayola", value="1130084632214384722"),
        discord.SelectOption(label="Light Blue", value="1130518862597730444"),
        discord.SelectOption(label="Pale Green", value="1130519060115890236")
    ]
    super().__init__(placeholder="Выбери цвет, который нравится", min_values=1, max_values=1, options=options)
async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.user.add_roles(interaction.guild.get_role(int(self.values[0])))
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Ты выбрал цвет <@&{self.values[0]}>", ephemeral=True)
```

I do not know how to write a condition so that the role is given to the user if he chooses another role...

Answer (score 0):

A bit different, but the logic is the same; get all the role ids in the options and make a list of roles. Then, use [remove_roles()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.remove_roles) to remove all the roles before adding the selected role.

```
class PastelColor(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    @discord.ui.select(
        options=[
        discord.SelectOption(label="Lemon Chiffon", value="1129910267531231313"),
        discord.SelectOption(label="Bluish White", value="1129910494719922186"),
        ]
    )
    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, select: discord.ui.Select):
        roles = [interaction.guild.get_role(int(o.value)) for o in select.options]
        await interaction.user.remove_roles(*roles, atomic=True)
        await interaction.user.add_roles(interaction.guild.get_role(int(select.values[0])))
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Ты выбрал цвет <@&{select.values[0]}>", ephemeral=True)
```

> atomic (bool) – Whether to atomically remove roles. This will ensure that multiple operations will always be applied regardless of the current state of the cache.

Atomic is set to true by default.

Comment: it doesn't work... AttributeError: 'TheGarageColorView' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: `select.values` not `self`, by which `select: discord.ui.Select`